# SMS Text normalization

Tags: java, sms, nlp

I am looking for a good library or some project that has been done in the area of SMS text normalization. I have found some good research projects like [this](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/sms/) one.

I am using Java as the programming language.

The concept in a nutshell is to handle SMS based text like "**tel him 2 go home nw**" and convert it to normal english language text "**tell him to go home now**".

Answer (score 4):

Why not just to download a dictionary from a site like this: http://smsdictionary.co.uk/abbreviations and use a string replacement?

Comment: This is definitely the simplest method.

Comment: That looks good and I have stumbled upon some text corpuses myself.
I tried converting some basic SMS text [here](http://smsdictionary.co.uk/index.html?p=t) like "**gnite**" or "**tomo**"and it fails to convert the text.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary substitution does not cut it, since it misses context in translations. e.g. do you translate '2' to 'to', 'too' or 'two'?

You can get a corpus and train a statistical model yourself, either using Moses (http://www.statmt.org/moses/) or Phrasal (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/phrasal/).

As an author of the Stanford one (http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/sms/translate.php), I could be convinced to offer a REST based API for such a service, but I don't know the demand for it...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Honestly , I would love to see a REST based API service for the same and don't think why would that be not needed by others. Its a common problem.